# Publishing SharePoint Application Page to a remote server

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, deployment, remote-server

I created a SharePoint Application Page. I chose Deploy as a Farm Solution and was able to make the application page work and get deployed on the local (development) SharePoint server. But apparently I cannot deploy (publish) a Farm Solution to a remote (users) server. My requirement is that I need to implement SharePoint Application Pages and deploy them to a remote server. But my problem is that if I choose Farm Solution, I can implement Application Pages but cannot publish to a remote server. But when I choose Sandbox solution I don't have the option to create application pages, the template says Application Page (Farm Solution only). What am I missing here? Why is the type of page related to the deployment target?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to package it up and deploy from the remote server using powershell: http://patrickboom.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/using-powershell-to-deploy-sharepoint-solutions-wsp-2/